# How to measure DOM rendering time Angular 2 app?

Tags: performance, angular, dom, rendering, benchmark.js

While I am develping web application using Angular 2, I came to have question about performance test like [how to measure loading time in Angular2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41861038/how-to-measure-loading-time-in-angular2). Therefore, I got a very helpful answer, I could start to do performance test. However, I would like to measure DOM rendering time also. My app is very content intensive, the rendering time can be quite a while. If someone knows how to use benchmark.js in order to DOM rendering, could you give some advice?

Answer (score 1):

[Lighthouse](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/lighthouse/) is an excellent tool for measuring performance. It powers the "audit" tab in the chrome developer extensions, but can also be run from command-line if needed.